# Spark LDA with scala and Java

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lda

In current, I have try implemented LDA algorithm using Apache Spark with scala following:

```
    // Filter out stopwords
val stopwords: Array[String] = sc.textFile("data/english_stops_words.txt").collect()
val filteredTokens = new StopWordsRemover()
  .setStopWords(stopwords)
  .setCaseSensitive(false)
  .setInputCol("words")
  .setOutputCol("filtered")
  .transform(tokens)

// Limit to top `vocabSize` most common words and convert to word count vector features
val cvModel = new CountVectorizer()
  .setInputCol("filtered")
  .setOutputCol("features")
  .setVocabSize(vocabSize)
  .fit(filteredTokens)
val countVectors = cvModel.transform(filteredTokens)
  .select("docId", "features")
  .map { case Row(docId: Long, countVector: Vector) => (docId, countVector) }
  .cache()
```

But after that, i convert this code from scala to Java API:

```
        // Filter out stopwords
    List<String> stopwords = sc.textFile("data/english_stops_words.txt")
            .collect();
    DataFrame filteredTokens = new StopWordsRemover()
            .setStopWords(stopwords.toArray(new String[0]))
            .setCaseSensitive(false).setInputCol("words")
            .setOutputCol("filtered").transform(tokens);

    // Limit to top `vocabSize` most common words and convert to word count
    // vector features
    CountVectorizerModel cvModel = new CountVectorizer()
            .setInputCol("filtered").setOutputCol("features")
            .setVocabSize(vocabSize).fit(filteredTokens);

    JavaRDD<TextId> countVectors = cvModel.transform(filteredTokens)
              .select("docId", "features").toJavaRDD()
              .map(new Function<Row, TextId>() {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public TextId call(Row row) throws Exception {

                    return new TextId(row.get(0).toString(), Long.parseLong(row.get(1).toString()));
                }
            }).cache();
```

But LDA model only accept JavaPairRDD parameter for run() function. I have stuck when try to parse countVectors as JavaPairRDD as scala code can do it.
Please help me if you have another solution.
Thank you very much.

EDITED:
I have change my code follow:

```
        JavaPairRDD<Long, Vector> countVectors = cvModel.transform(filteredTokens)
              .select("docId", "features").toJavaRDD()
              .mapToPair(new PairFunction<Row, Long, Vector>() {
                public Tuple2<Long, Vector> call(Row row) throws Exception {
                    return new Tuple2<Long, Vector>(Long.parseLong(row.getString(0)), Vectors.dense(row.getDouble(1)));
                }
            }).cache();
```

Many thank to @Till Rohrmann.
But after run program, I have exception message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.Column.as(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/Metadata;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Column;
>       at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover.transform(StopWordsRemover.scala:144)

Can you help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mapToPair` method to create a `JavaPairRDD`.

Assuming that `TextId` has a `String` and a `Long` field the code could look the following:

```java
JavaPairRDD<Long, Vector> countVectors = cvModel.transform(filteredTokens)
  .select("docId", "features").toJavaRDD()
  .mapToPair(new PairFunction<Row, Long, Vector>() {
    public Tuple2<Long, Vector> call(Row row) throws Exception {
        return new Tuple2<String, Long>(row.getAs[Long](0), row.getAs[Vector](1)));
    }
}).cache();
```

Comment: I'm very, very sorry about my mistake, but LDA model in spark accept parameter JavaPairRDD<Long, Vector> not JavaPairRDD<String, Long>.
Can you help me to resolve this problem

Comment: Sure, then you simply have to parse the `Vector` from the second column. I will update my solution.

Comment: I have error when try
 return new Tuple2<Long, Vector>(row.getAs[Long](0), row.getAs[Vector](1)));
Can you update another solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have change code as I edited my question.
But, I got exception when using class StopWordsRemover. The message is: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.Column.as(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/Metadata;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Column;
Can you help me with this exception?

Comment: Which version do you use to run the Spark job? The method `Column.as` is only there since version `1.3.0`. I assume that you used a Spark version `>=1.3.0` to build your job jar but an older version `<1.3.0` to run your job. Is this possible?

Comment: I run Spark job with the latest version 1.5.1.

Comment: IDE throw exception in line DataFrame filteredTokens = new StopWordsRemover(). When I try to create new DataFrame  from remove stop word.

Comment: The `NoSuchMethodError`? Could you append the complete stack trace to your question?

Comment: I have re-check my code. And I have founded that may be root cause happened when I create DataFrame tokens = new RegexTokenizer().
Can you help me refer to my log file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B59AIUOtxyrDZ2w5RnduLXdKbjg/view?usp=sharing
Thank you very much.

Comment: @Thanh Thai Nguyen did you ever get this working in java? I'm trying to do the same thing. What does your input look like? Is it JSON? Does the input have docId field?

Comment: @AbuSulaiman I have resolved this problem by using another way. Because at current CountVectorizerModel  does not as well as for Java version. In scala version, everything is ok.

Comment: @ThanhThaiNguyen could you share how you solved this issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Hi @ChristopherRicha So happy when I can help you. Here is exactly I have done with LDA: http://pastebin.com/h0vR3UD4